# How to set the ckeditor content in my reactjs project?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor

I want to set the aboutCompamy in my in reactjs project. I used ckEditor. I does not work properly as I desire. Actually when I set it, the log result is one character less. What is wrong and how may I fix it?

```
 <CKEditor
         editor={ClassicEditor}
         config={{
                    language: getLanguage(),
                    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', 'blockQuote', 'link', 'numberedList', 'bulletedList', 'imageUpload', 'insertTable', 'tableColumn', 'tableRow', 'mergeTableCells', 'mediaEmbed', '|', 'undo', 'redo']
                                        }}
         data={companyInfo.about}
         onReady={editor => {
                 // You can store the "editor" and use when it is needed.
                  console.log('Editor is ready to use!', editor);
         }}
         onChange={async (event, editor) => {
                 setAboutCompany(editor.getData());
                 console.log(aboutCompany);
         }}
         onBlur={(event, editor) => {
               //console.log('Blur.', editor);
         }}
         onFocus={(event, editor) => {
               //console.log('Focus.', editor);
         }}
    />
```

Comment: are you referring to this: `setAboutCompany(editor.getData());
                 console.log(aboutCompany);` ? If yes, problem is setState will show new value on new render.